# Prevent uploading .sh files to server uisng php

Tags: php

Currently in my code the extension of the files is checked before it is uploaded to the server. I need to check the content of the files too before uploading it to server. I have used the following code

```
    $FileName = $_FILES[$imageInput]['name'];
    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    $mtype = finfo_file($finfo, $FileName);
```

$mtype is correctly identified for all image type like .png , .jpg but it doesn't recognised .sh files. How can I check this using php? Some one please help.

Comment: you could test if the filename ends with `.sh`?

Answer (score 0):

You can block various files to be executed via `.htaccess`. For example you can place this

```
<FilesMatch "\.(sh|cgi.+)$">
    ForceType text/plain
</FilesMatch>
```

This will ensure files in the folder will return as **text/plain**

If you want you can detect mime type as you detect for images. Mime type for `.sh` is

```
application/x-sh
application/x-csh
text/x-shellscript
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can try cross-validate between mime type and extension by taking the extension through the following scripts:

`$fileExtension= end(explode(".", $_FILES["uploadedFile"]["name"]));`

or

`$fileName = ($_FILES['uploadedFile']['name']);`

`$fileExtension = pathinfo($fileName , PATHINFO_EXTENSION);`

And later, apply something like:

```
$finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
if (false === $fileExtension = array_search(
    $finfo->file($_FILES['uploadedFile']['tmp_name']),
    array(
        //'sh' => 'text/x-shellscript', //not allowed
        'docx'  => 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
        'rtf' => 'text/rtf',
        'odt' => 'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text',
        'txt' => 'text/plain',
        'pdf' => 'application/pdf',
    ),
    true
)) {
     $error .= "<br> The allowed file format file are: \"doc\", \"docx\", \"rtf\", \"odt\", \"txt\", \"pdf\"' ";
}
```

I had a problem similar to this, but in my case the file was `.rtf` type.

The `FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE` function apparently can not capture any type of file extension, this can lead to some validation errors.

Some examples:
The default mime type for .rtf files is `application/rtf`, but the `FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE` function displays `text/rtf`.

I wasted a lot of time trying to solve this bug as I described it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55463047/the-rtf-file-extension-is-disappearing-during-the-execution-of-the-mime-extens/55483845):

In the case of `.sh` files I noticed that the `FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE` function can not capture the extension, it returns me a null value